# What's the different between ipmitool power cycle and reboot?

Tags: linux, ipmitool

I'm a newbie in linux. So, could anyone tell me what's the difference between ipmitool power cycle and reboot? Thanks.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

IPMI cycle performs a cold reboot. Cold means that shutdown is not done in an orderly manner and the synchronizations with the underlying filesystem does not happen so you could possibly lose some data that was cached in page cache memory and not committed to the storage.

While the "reboot" command line tool performs a warm reboot and hence no data loss could occur.

More on cold/warm reboot here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot_(computing)#